# Jets of Equivariant Vector Bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, equivariant, homogeneous-spaces, jets, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a (compact) $G$-homogeneous space with fibre group $H$, and let ${\cal E}$ be a $G$-equivariant $k$-dimensional vector bundle over $M$ with corresponding representation $\pi:H \to $R$^k$. What I would like to know is whether all the jet bundles  (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_bundle) for a definition of jet bundle) of $\cal E$ are also $G$-equivariant, and if so, can one construct their corresponding representations from $\pi$?

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes: since $G$ acts by bundle morphisms on $\mathcal{E}$ it will induce an action on sections, which preserves tangency of sections, hence induces an action on jets. Concerning the second questions: if I'm not mistake the representation $\pi:H\to R^k$ determines at least locally up to isomorphism the action of $G$ on the bundle, hence you should also be able to reconstruct the representation of $H$ on the fibers of jets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your terminology, but I'm gonna try to answer your question anyway. Let $M=G/H$ and let $\mathbb{E}$ be a representation of $H$. By $E$ I denote the associated homogeneous vector bundle $G/H \times_H \mathbb{E}$. The jet space of $E$ is also a homogeneous vector bundle which is induced from the $(\mathfrak{g},H)$-representation $J_{eH}(E)$, i.e. from the representation which is induced on the fiber over identity coset. There is a duality between $J_{eH}(E)$ and $\mathfrak{U(g)\otimes_{U(h)}} \mathbb{E}^*$.

Some details can be found in the  appendix of [this](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~esiprpr/esi722.pdf) ESI preprint. For applications to invariant differential operators see [Differential opperators on homogeneous spaces](http://www.math.okstate.edu/~zierau/papers/ICE/ICE-course.pdf) by L. Barchini and R. Zierau.

Comment: So then what is the explicit representation of $H$ on $\frak{U(g)}\otimes _{\frak{U(h)}}$ $E^*$. I'm guessing that its the tensor product of the dual rep of $H$ on $E$ with some rep of $H$ on $\frak{U(g)}$.

Comment: Yes. I believe that the representation of $H$ on $\mathfrak{U(g)\otimes_{U(h)}\mathbb{E}^*$ is the tensor product of representation on $\mathfrak{U(g)}$ and the dual representation on $\mathbb{E}$. The representation of $H$ on the universal enveloping algebra is the extension of the adjoint representation of $H$ on $\mathfrak{g}$. 

Unfortunately, I'm quite busy at the moment so I can't check the details and to be honest I do not know of better references other than that I've already given in the answer. Hopefully somebody will fill that gap.

Comment: Yes, that fills the gap!

Comment: I have also found the reference "Invariant Differential Operators" by W. Smoke (1967) to be a concise but clear introduction to the basics of invariant differential operators and the relationship with the jet bundle and jet algebras over a homogeneous space.

Answer (score 2):

See chapter IV and  section 32 (and others) of the book:
Ivan Kolár, Jan Slovák, Peter W. Michor: Natural operations in differential geometry. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, Heidelberg, New York, (1993)
[(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf).